# Can I install Linux on these AmLogic single-board computer?

Tags: system-installation, raspbian, arm

A company called MECOOL offers several "TV box" devices, based on AmLogic single-board computers (SBC's). Examples: [KM2](https://www.banggood.com/Mecool-KM7-Amlogic-S905Y4-4GB-RAM-64GB-ROM-bluetooth-4_2-5G-Wifi-Android-11-4K-HDR10+-TV-Box-Support-4K-Youtube-HDTV2_1-AV1-VP9-H_265-Decoder-p-1898212.html) [KM6](https://www.banggood.com/MECOOL-KM6-ATV-Classic-Amlogic-S905X4-2GB-SDRAM-16GB-ROM-bluetooth-4_2-5G-WiFi-Android-10_0-4K-HDR-TV-Box-Support-Google-Assistant-4K-Youtube-Prime-Video-AV1-4K-at-60fps-H_265-VP9-p-1801454.html), [KM6 Deluxe](https://www.banggood.com/MECOOL-KM6-ATV-Deluxe-Amlogic-S905X4-4GB-SDRAM-64GB-ROM-bluetooth-5_0-5G-WiFi6-Android-10_0-TV-Box-Support-Google-Assistant-4K-Youtube-Prime-Video-AV1-4K-at-60fps-H_265-VP9-1000M-LAN-Ethernet-p-1801347.html). They sport quad-core ARM Cortex CPUs (A55, A35), have 2 or 4 GB of RAM, and ship with Android 10 or Android 11.

I would like to replace their OS with a Linux distribution. It would be nice if it could just be generic, but something oriented to this kind of boxes (like Raspbian for the Raspberry Pi) would also be fine.

Is this possible? And if not - is it impossible for *all* AmLogic-based SBCs, or just for this specific series?

Comment: It's certainly **possible**, but it may not be **practical** for you - somebody needs to put in the work to prepare a Linux installation for that system, including a way to boot, and including a way to move it onto the existing system somehow. If nobody has done this before (at least Google finds nothing), then you either need to do it yourself, and if you don't have the skills to do it, you need to pay someone to do it, or wait until someone else has done it.

Comment: And if it helps: here's a [guide](http://www.galipe.net/guide-mecool-m8sproplus-armbian/) (in French) on how to use Armbian on an Mecool M8S Pro Plus. Something similar may or may not work for your hardware choices.